# javascript and es6 filter array with unique key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list in variable like:

```
var name_list = some_list

console.log(name_list)

Array[3]
   0: Object
       name: "Johny"
   1: Object
       name: "Monty"
   2: Object3:
      name: "Johny"
```

I want to get the list with `non repetitive` list.
How can I do this ?

**Update**

I tried with this..

```
var unique_name = [ ...new Set(name_list.map(name => {
                return name.name
            }))]
```

It works fine but I want the `object` that are filtered unique according to name.

Any idea ??

Comment: use es6 feature [set](https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2014/es6-one-liners-to-show-off/) `[ ...new Set(array) ]`

Comment: @diEcho or anyone else, any ideas why `[ ...new Set(array) ]` doesn't work?

Comment: will it gives uniquey according to name.. what if there are other values too like age, sex but I want accorgint to name

Comment: Do you want a deduped list of names, or an array with the duplicate objects removed?

Comment: arry with duplicate object removed... that duplication should be name..

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald try `Array.from(new Set(array))`

Comment: @colinfang Isn't that basically the same as what diEcho wrote?

Answer (score 4):

`reduce` over the array keeping a lookup of previous entries to check against.

```js
const arr=[{name:"Johny"},{name:"Monty"},{name:"Johny"}];

function dedupeByKey(arr, key) {
  const tmp = {};
  return arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    const k = c[key];
    if (tmp[k]) return p;
    tmp[k] = true;
    return p.concat(c);
  }, []);
}

console.log(dedupeByKey(arr, 'name'));
```

Or you can `filter` using a similar approach:

```js
const arr=[{name:"Johny"},{name:"Monty"},{name:"Johny"}];

function dedupeByKey(arr, key) {
  const temp = arr.map(el => el[key]);
  return arr.filter((el, i) =>
    temp.indexOf(el[key]) === i
  );
}

console.log(dedupeByKey(arr, 'name'));
```

Comment: I like your second approach

Answer (score 4):

Another approach I don't see in here would be to use a `Map`

```
var name_list = [{name: "Johny"}, {name: "Monty"}, {name: "Johny"}];

// Make a mapping of name to object, then pullout objects.
var name_map = new Map(name_list.map(o => [o.name, o]));
var unique_names = [...name_map.values()];
```

Note, this will take the *last* object for each name instead of the first, but you could always do `name_list.slice().reverse().map(` instead of you need specifically the first object found.

Comment: The best of the lot IMO!

Answer (score 2):

Filter to keep only those elements which are the first occurrence of the name (in other words, whose index is the same as the index of the first occurrence):

```js
var name_list = [{name: "Johny"}, {name: "Monty"}, {name: "Johny"}];

var filtered = name_list . filter(
  (elt, i, a) => i === a.findIndex(
    elt2 => elt.name === elt2.name
  )
);

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(filtered);
```

```html
<pre id='result'></pre>
```

This might not be the fastest approach, but it could be the simplest.

Comment: A+ for keeping it simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use this little `distinctByProp( theArray, propertyName)` function.

I hope it helps

```
distinctByProp = (theArray, prop) => {
    let tempArray = [];
    let isFound = obj => tempArray.find( n => n[prop] === obj[prop]);
    theArray.forEach( current => !isFound(current) && tempArray.push(current));
    return tempArray;
}
```

Usage is like:

```
let names_list = [{name: "Johny"}, {name: "Johnyh"}, {name: "Max"}, {name: "Monty"}, {name: "Johnyh"}, {name: "Max"}];

let distinct = distinctByProp(names_list, "name");

console.log(distinct);
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
var name_list = [{ name: "Johny" }, { name: "Monty" }, { name: "Johny" }],
    filtered = name_list.filter(a => {
        this.my = this.my || Object.create(null);
        if (!this.my[a.name]) {
            this.my[a.name] = true;
            return true;
        }
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(filtered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: If you know how arrow functions work then you know that passing `Object.create(null)` is pointless and your code might fail.

Comment: can use `({})` instead of `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @diEcho, no, you get otherwise all prototypes of Object.

Answer (score 0):

This is my resumed form of this type of unique. Not only for one field but for all the root fields of the object.

```
const unique = l => l.filter(
  (e1, i, a) => i === a.findIndex(
    e2 => Object.keys(e1)
      .map(x => e1[x] === e2[x])
      .reduce((x,y) => x && y)
  )
)
```