# How to filter an array of objects by the object's key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I am struggling a lot with this.
I have an array of objects and i want to filter it by key, which means if the array has two object with a certain key i only need to keep the last object.

```
const mockdata = [
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    status: null,
    visibility: 'thid',
  },
];
```

To look like:

```
const mockdata = [
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    status: null,
    visibility: 'false',
  },
];
```

Comment: Duplicated here: [javascript and es6 filter array with unique key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37021649/14032355)

Comment: Why is it `status: null,
    visibility: 'false',`? How it it turn to `'false'`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve exactly. What is the key for you, only `id` and `status`? Because you seem to ignore `visibility`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let mockdata = [
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    id: null,
    visibility: 'true',
  },
  {
    status: null,
    visibility: 'thid',
  },
];

mockdata = mockdata.filter((data, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.id === data.id && t.visibility === data.visibility && t.status === data.status
  ))
)
```

While filtering , I am checking for the index using Array.findIndex which returns the index of first item that matches with the condition , so non unique values are not counted